# I can't reach Input.value on table

Tags: javascript, html, web, input, get

I need to get value of input in table cell. but when ı use innerHTML and value i just get undefined.

```js
function myDeleteFunction(id) {
var sıra=id;
//var sıra=document.getElementById("sıraınput").value;
var tablesepet = document.getElementById("sepet");
for (var i = 1; i < tablesepet.rows.length; i++) {
    alert(tablesepet.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML.value);
    /*if (tablesepet.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML==sıra) {
        alert("fff");
        //tablesepet.deleteRow(sıra);
    }*/
}


count=count-1;

}
```

```js
//I tried thoose 

tablesepet.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML.value
tablesepet.rows[i].cells[0].value
tablesepet.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML

//nothing work
```

this is deletefunction and this is my table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYYXZ.png)

Comment: What does the html for the table look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use querySelector to get the input element

```
tablesepet.rows[i].cells[0].querySelector("input, select, textarea").value
```